# Cannot convert double to double

Tags: c

```
void load(int *n, double *x, double **arr, bool randomize)
{
    *arr = (double*)malloc((*n + 1) * sizeof(double));
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i <= *n; i++)
    {
        if(! randomize)
        {   
            scanf("%lf", *arr + i);
        }
        else
        {
            *(arr + i) = rand();
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the `randomize` parameter I want to fill the array with random or custom double numbers. This code however does not compile, it displays `"invalid conversion from int to double"` in else section.

Replacing `rand()` with any float value like 5.0 shows "cannot convert double to double" instead.

`(double) rand()` or `(double) 5` throw similar errors.

`*n` of course is read earlier in this function, I just cut it off here.

What can be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are quoting is incomplete. It's missing an asterisk after `double`: the type of `*(arr + i)` is `double*` rather than `double`, and you can't convert `int` or `double` to `double*`.

Presumably you mean

```
        *(*arr + i) = rand();
```

or

```
        (*arr)[i] = rand();
```

Comment: Uhh, learning pointers and references in C is quite fu*cking difficult ;-) Thanks!

Comment: @user2251921: You are welcome. BTW, references in C are easy -- there aren't any! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`*(arr + i) = rand();` -> `(*arr)[i] = rand();`